# Manipulating DOM of a specific socket using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sockets

I'm currently trying to make a chat application with Socket.io and I have two forms set up. One form is for username and the other for messages.

First, the page will only show the username form until it receives an input. Then the username form will disappear when the user submits the information. I am able to access this form using jQuery $(this). However, I would also like to make the message form appear using show() after I retrieve a user connection.

The function looks like this:

```
socket.on('user connected', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg + " has connected"));
    console.log($(this))
});
```

But i noticed that $(this) will only return the socket node. How do I go about retrieving the message form of that specific socket? If i just write $('form#message').show(), then all sockets will reveal the message form, which is not what I want.

This is my HTML body

```
    <ul id="messages"></ul>

    <form id="user" action="">
        <input id="user" autocomplete="off" />
        <button>Enter</button>
        </input>
    </form>

    <form id="message" action="">
        <input id="message" autocomplete="off" />
        <button>Send</button>
        </input>
    </form>
```

Comment: Please include your HTML as well.

Comment: @doublesharp ok i added the html body